# How to avoid ISOTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, error, governorlimits

I received the following error:

> Error: Invalid Data. 
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger ISOTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ISOTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

In the debug log I've found the following:

```
15:11:56.0 (762902111)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[94]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsRecurrence, RecurrenceActivityId FROM Task WHERE (IsClosed = FALSE AND (IsRecurrence = TRUE OR RecurrenceActivityId = '') AND AccountId = :tmpVar1)
15:11:56.0 (762942801)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[94]|System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
15:11:56.0 (763220286)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Class.AccountHandler.beforeUpdate: line 94, column 1
Class.TriggerFactory.execute: line 95, column 1
Class.TriggerFactory.createHandler: line 29, column 1
Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 3, column 1

15:11:56.0 (763234604)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101
```

Here is the code in method beforeUpdate and AccountHandler class:

```
public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) {

   for(SObject bu :Trigger.new) {
       Account a = (Account) bu;

       List<Task> tasksFromDatabase = new List<Task> ([SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsRecurrence, RecurrenceActivityId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND (IsRecurrence = true OR RecurrenceActivityId = '') AND AccountId = :a.Id]);

       String agentName = a.Agents__c;
       String recruiterName = a.Recruiter__c;//TO DO ::: delete, not used

       if(agentName != null) {
           List<ISOs__c>isoName = [SELECT Name, Recruiter_ID_num__c, Active__c FROM ISOs__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT ISO_Company__c FROM Agent__c WHERE Id = :agentName)];
           if(isoName.size() > 0) {
               if(isoName[0].Active__c == false) {
                   a.ISO_Name__c.addError('The selected agent is linked to an inactive Iso');
               }

           a.ISO_Name__c = isoName[0].Name;
           a.ISO_recruiter_id__c = IsoName[0].Recruiter_ID_num__c;
           }
       } else if(agentName == null) {
           a.ISO_Name__c = '';
           a.ISO_recruiter_id__c = '';
       }

       for(SObject sob :Trigger.new) {
           Account ab = (Account) sob;
           Account oldAB = (Account)Trigger.oldMap.get(ab.id);
           if (ab.Status__c != null && oldAB.Status__c!=null) {       
               if(ab.Status__c != oldAB.Status__c) {   
                   statusmail mail = new statusmail();
                   mail.setAccountInfo(ab);
                   mail.SendAccountEmail();            
                   if(ab.Agents__c != null)
                       mail.sendAgentEmail();
                   if(ab.Recruiter__c != null)
                       mail.sendRecruiterEmail();
               }
           }
       }       
    }
}
```

Please advise how to avoid this error?

Comment: you have multiple soql statements inside a for loop - please read up on trigger bulkification (trailhead, apex doc, google)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bulkification 101

This is the most basic pattern to bulkify code. You need to build your entire coding paradigm around *collections*, not individual records. You should query the records you need *before* your loop and cache them in a `Map` for retrieval later on.

### Child Records

It looks like all of your queries are for child data, so this is the basic principle you need to apply.

#### Incorrect Bulkification

```
for (/*loop definition*/)
{
    List<ChildObject__c> childRecords = [/*query*/];
}
```

#### Correct Bulkification

```
Map<Id, List<ChildObject__c>> parentToChildren = new Map<Id, List<ChildObject__c>>();
for (ChildObject__c child : [/*child query*/])
{
    if (!parentToChildren.containsKey(child.Parent__c))
        parentToChildren.put(child.Parent__c, new List<ChildObject__c>());
    parentToChildren.get(child.Parent__c).add(child);
}

for (/*original loop definition*/)
{
    List<ChildObject__c> children = parentToChildren.get(loopRecord.Id);
}
```

### Parent Records

The pattern for parent records is similar, and you should familiarize yourself with the idea here as well.

#### Incorrect Bulkification

```
for (/*loop definition*/)
{
    ParentObject__c parent = [/*query*/];
}
```

#### Correct Bulkification

```
Map<Id, ParentObject__c> parents = new Map<Id, ParentObject__c>([/*parent query*/]);
// if you need to map parents by Id, you can leverage the built in constructor

for (/*original loop definition*/)
{
    ParentObject__c parent = parents.get(loopRecord.ParentId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two queries in a for loop. Here's the solution if you want to remove the first query from the for loop. You have to do the same for ISOs__c query.

```
public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so) {

   List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
   for(SObject bu :Trigger.new) {
       Account a = (Account) bu;
       accountIds.add(a.Id);
   }

   Map<Id, List<Task>> tasksByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Task>>();
   for(Task task : [SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsRecurrence, RecurrenceActivityId, AccountId FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false AND (IsRecurrence = true OR RecurrenceActivityId = '') AND AccountId in :accountIds]){
      if(tasksByAccountId.containsKey(task.AccountId)){
         tasksByAccountId.get(task.AccountId).add(task);
      }else{
         List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(){task};
         taskByAccountId.put(task.AccountId, tasks);
      }
   }

   for(SObject bu :Trigger.new) {
       Account a = (Account) bu;

       List<Task> tasksFromDatabase = taskByAccountId.get(a.Id);
```

Comment: FYI your code will be more efficient if you take advantage of [for loop batching](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm). You also left a query in the for loop.

Comment: Sorry for the missing for loop batching. I mentioned the second query in the for loop. I was just trying to show him how to do it and leaving him some work.

Comment: That might be more clear if you just trim out the code you didn't fix. :)

Comment: Yes sorry.... You're right. As always !