# Too many SOQL queries: 101 in a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller

I'm getting Too many SOQL queries: 101 in a VF page, Could you please advise how I can fix it?

```
 for (OpportunityLineItem opline: opp.OpportunityLineItems)
        {   
            Opwrap = new OppProductWrapper();
           
          Opwrap.OppId = opp.Id;
           if(opp.ContractId!=null){
                Opwrap.Contract = opp.ContractId;
                 Con = [Select Total_Amount__c,Name,StartDate,EndDate,Status from Contract Where Id =: opp.ContractId limit 1];
                 Opwrap.StartDate = Con.StartDate;
                 Opwrap.EndDate = Con.EndDate;
                 Opwrap.ContractStatus = Con.Status;
               Opwrap.ContractName = Con.Name;
               Opwrap.ContractAmount=Con.Total_Amount__c;
               
           }
```

Comment: You should not write soql query inside loop. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid ISOTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155117/how-to-avoid-isotrigger-system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101)

Comment: Please check the accepted answer from this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155117/how-to-avoid-isotrigger-system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101

Answer (score 4):

This all seems to be relatively unnecessary. You can get all of this information in a single query. No need to wrap and no need to query in a loop:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([
    SELECT Id, Contract.Total_Amount__c, Contract.Name, 
        Contract.StartDate, Contract.EndDate, (
            SELECT Id
            FROM OpportunityLineItems
        )
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Id in :oppIds
]);
```

The just loop through the records to do what you need to do:

```
for (Opportunity triggerOpp : Trigger.new) {
    for (OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.OpportunityLineItems) {
        Opportunity referenceOpp = oppMap.get(triggerOpp.Id);
        system.debug(referenceOpp.Contract.Total_Amount__c);
    }
}
```

Or maybe:

```
for(OpportunityLineItem triggerOli : Trigger.new) {
    Opportunity referenceOpp = oppMap.get(triggerOli.OpportunityId);
    triggerOli.ContractId = referenceOpp.ContractId;
}
```

Or for a VF Page:

```
public List<Opportunity> opps {get; set;}

public controllerConstructor(ApexPages.standardSetController setCon) {
    this.opps = getOpps(setCon.getRecords());
}

public controllerConstructor(ApexPages.standardController stdCon) {
    this.opps = getOpps(new List<Opportunity{stdCon.getRecord()});
}

public List<Opportunity> getOpps(List<Opportunity> oppsToGet) {
    List<Opportunity> result;

    if (oppsToGet != null && !oppsToGet.isEmpty()) {
        result = [
            SELECT Id, Contract.Total_Amount__c, Contract.Name, 
                Contract.StartDate, Contract.EndDate, (
                   SELECT Id
                    FROM OpportunityLineItems
                )
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE Id in :oppsToGet
        ];
    }

    return result;
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!opps}" var="opp">
    <apex:datatable value="{!opp.OpportunityLineItems}" var="oli">
        <apex:column value="{!opp.Contract.Total_Amount__c}"/>
    </apex:datatable>
</apex:repeat>
```

If you do NEED to wrap it (for instance, if you're adding a checkbox to allow users to select rows):

```
public class OppWrapper {
    public Opportunity obj {get; set;}
    public List<OppLineWrapper> wrappedOlis {get; set;}

    public OppWrapper (Opportunity record) {
        this.obj = record;
        this.wrappedOlis  = new List<OppLineWrapper>();
        
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : record.OpportunityLineItems) {
            this.wrappedOlis.add(new OppLineWrapper(oli));
        }
    }
}

public class OppLineWrapper {
    public OpportunityLineItem obj {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public classOppLineWrapper(OpportunityLineItem record) {
        this.obj = record;
        this.selected = false;
    }
}

public controllerConstructor(ApexPages.standardSetController setCon) {
    this.opps = new List<OppWrapper>();

    for (Opportunity opp : getOpps(setCon.getRecords()) {
        this.opps.add(new OppWrapper(opp));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like opp is a variable declared out of the for loop, so simply, you can try this:

```
    Con = [Select Total_Amount__c,Name,StartDate,EndDate,Status from Contract Where Id =: opp.ContractId limit 1];

    for (OpportunityLineItem opline: opp.OpportunityLineItems) {   
       Opwrap = new OppProductWrapper();
       Opwrap.OppId = opp.Id;

       if(opp.ContractId!=null){
            Opwrap.Contract = opp.ContractId;
            Opwrap.StartDate = Con.StartDate;
            Opwrap.EndDate = Con.EndDate;
            Opwrap.ContractStatus = Con.Status;
            Opwrap.ContractName = Con.Name;
            Opwrap.ContractAmount=Con.Total_Amount__c;
       }
    }
```

In case you mean opline instead of opp, you should try this:

```
Set<Id> oplineContractIds = new Set<Id>();
for (OpportunityLineItem opline: opp.OpportunityLineItems) { 
    oplineContractIds.add(opline.ContractId);
}

Map<Id, Contract> contracts = new Map<Id, Contract>([Select Total_Amount__c,Name,StartDate,EndDate,Status from Contract Where Id IN :oplineContractIds]);

    for (OpportunityLineItem opline: opp.OpportunityLineItems) {   
       Opwrap = new OppProductWrapper();
       Opwrap.OppId = opline.Id;

       if(opp.ContractId!=null){
            Opwrap.Contract = opline.ContractId;
            Contract con = contracts.get(opline.ContractId);
            Opwrap.StartDate = Con.StartDate;
            Opwrap.EndDate = Con.EndDate;
            Opwrap.ContractStatus = Con.Status;
            Opwrap.ContractName = Con.Name;
            Opwrap.ContractAmount=Con.Total_Amount__c;
       }
    }
```